# Loud snap and there is now noise when turning steering left and right

Tags: vw, golf, struts

While I was driving 20 mph, I heard a loud snap/bang noise and the car then started making noise when turning the steering wheel or driving on small bumps. Any idea what could cause this? Broken struts?

This is a 2013 Volkswagen Golf Mk6 with approximately 40K miles. I just had to change the rear brake pads because they rusted (as I don't drive enough?)

Comment: What kind of noise? Does it make noise when stationary? Wheres it coming from?

Comment: It does make the noise when stationary, when rotating the steering from left to right, it makes a clunking noise.. it is pretty loud, can be heard from outside too. Comes from driver side, front left wheel.

Comment: Can you have someone turn the wheel while you look for the noise? I’d suspect the spring broke. How’s the ride height?

Comment: I will check tomorrow! It did not seem like height changed that much but the noise was very very loud. It also felt like there was a piece of wood underneath the car touching something when driving over bumps.

Comment: When driving what's the ride like? Does it pull in either direction after the noise? If someone pushes down on the front left corner with the engine off do you hear the noise?

Comment: Brought the car to a mechanic, front driver side coil spring broke, they have to replace both.. quoted me about 500 USD.

Comment: Answer your question with your findings. Sometimes they sell a strut spring assembly you can bolt in and have the car aligned afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brought the car to a mechanic, front driver side coil spring broke. They have to replace both. Quoted me about 500 USD for 2.5 hours of labour & OEM parts from dealership.

Answer (score 1):

Might be that your steering pump went bad too maybe the polley or bearrings inside broke.

Did you feel like you have to use a lot more power than usual to make turns???
If u do big chance that might be it..!!